# Error running BlackBerry app from Eclipse

Tags: java, blackberry

I am developing an app with 65 class files.  I recently re-installed Eclipse and now I can't run the app:

> I/O Error: Cannot run program "jar":
>   CreateProcess error=2 The system
>   cannot find the file specified

I checked my Java_Path and I don't see any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running only a `JRE` you need a `JDK` .  echo out your `JAVA_HOME` variable and tell us what it says.

Comment: Echo out JAVA_HOME variable means? Sorry but i'm not getting. I tried from command prompt and getting when i check Echo out to my Java path it returns OUT. is it proper way or not, plz tell me.

Comment: type this in the prompt echo %JAVA_HOME% .  Assuming that JAVA_HOME is on your path and this is how you configured your java home to be